# php(WP) odata webservice de Busines central

Tags: php, wordpress, webservice, odata

Tengo este código con el que estoy intentando consumir un webService desde page.php de wordpres.
si utilizo  $urlOdata,$username,$password puedo consumir el webService en el navegador.
Pero en la pagina web me regresa:"12bool(false) 3resource(1841) of type (stream-context) Resource id #1841"
Me gustaría recibir y mostrar el json q envía el webservice.

```
<?php

        $urlOdata="enlace";
        $username="usuario";
        $password="pass";
        try{
            $call_opts=array(
                "http"=>array(
                    "method"=>"GET",
                    "header"=>"Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode($username.":".$password)."\r\n"."Content-Type: application/json",
            ));
            $call_context=stream_context_create($call_opts);
            $call_res_json=file_get_contents($urlOdata,false);
            print("1");
            print($call_res_json);
            print("2");
            var_dump($call_res_json);
            print("3");
            var_dump($call_context);
            echo $call_context;
        }catch (Exception $e) {
             echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";    
        }
     ?>
```

Muchas gracias por la atención.

Comment: y cual es la pregunta o error?

Comment: Me gustaria mostrar el json que regresa el webservice :)

Comment: esos no es un error o problema ... es una tarea.